# Protonation of compounds with two or three neighboring nitrogens

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am working with organic compounds. Many of them are similar to this ones:

[image: Molecules]

The R group (which I paste for completeness) is:

[image: R-group]

I am a bit confused about the protonation state of those amine-compounds at **pH=7.4, in aqueous solution**.

N-substitued amines are more basic than the other ones. For example methylamine is more basic than ammonia.
But the protonation state of the *ring* is more complex than that, and I can't understand how to protonate it.

I suppose that in a kind of analogy with the guanidine (product) we could protonate again the double bonded nitrogen (imine).

Will amine be protonated? Will that compound has $+2$ charge?

**Guanidine**

It will possibly be protonated in the double bounded nitrogen, because it has more negative density charge and resonation is not broken. Any other point of view will be welcome.

Comment: These are [guanidines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanidine) and it's imino group which gets protonated - it's not "secondary amine".

Comment: This is quite similar to the question that [I am trying to reason as well.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/80426/7450)

Comment: " with two or three neighboring nitrogens" There's no two nitrogens right next to each other in these structures...